# Flask-SQLAlchemy Relationship errors

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm building an API with Flask and SQLAlchemy and have created a relationship between 2 tables. When I run the project all seems to work fine and also the tests work when run via `python manage.py test`, however if I run the tests using the PyTest command or via PyCharm then it throws an error for initializing mapper. The relationship is to be able to get all the `SearchTeams` on the `Search` object using the `teams` name

The error is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Search->searches, expression 'SearchTeam' failed to locate a name ('SearchTeam'). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'app.models.Search.Search'> class after both dependent classes have been defined.
```

The models are:

Search:

```py
class Search(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'searches'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    location = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.today)
    start_time = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)
    end_time = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(255))
    oic = db.Column(db.String(255))
    sm = db.Column(db.String(255))
    so = db.Column(db.String(255))
    sl = db.Column(db.String(255))
    ro = db.Column(db.String(255))
    scribe = db.Column(db.String(255))
    notes = db.Column(db.Text)

    teams = db.relationship('SearchTeam', backref='search')

    def __init__(self, location, date, start_time, type, oic, sm, so, sl, ro, scribe):
        self.location = location
        self.date = date
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.type = type
        self.oic = oic
        self.sm = sm
        self.so = so
        self.sl = sl
        self.ro = ro
        self.scribe = scribe
```

SearchTeam:

```py
class SearchTeam(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'search_teams'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    uuid = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), unique=True, nullable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    search_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('searches.id'))
    team_leader = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    medic = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    responder_1 = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    responder_2 = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    responder_3 = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)

    def __init__(self, search, team_leader, medic, responder_1, responder_2, responder_3):
        self.search = search
        self.team_leader = team_leader
        self.medic = medic
        self.responder_1 = responder_1
        self.responder_2 = responder_2
        self.responder_3 = responder_3
```

Comment: It looks like `Search` has no attribute `searches` in the example code, so the error message and the models don't match a 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging around, I was able to get this working by simply importing the `SearchTeam` model into the `Search` model.

Not 100% sure on why/how this fixes it as other projects where I've used similar relationships don't require this, but it's working now which is the main thing.

Comment: Was `SearchTeam` imported at all anywhere before using the models the first time (which triggers configuration)?

Comment: @IljaEverilä It wasn't, just updated a bit to test that theory but still same issue. Tried using same architecture that I use in other projects but didn't work.

Comment: That is the usual issue. SQLA has certain lookups/registries it uses to handle string lookups, but in order for the mapped class to be found, it has to have been constructed before use. For example `db.create_all()` uses the models, so all classes must have been evaluated before it is called.

Comment: Intersting. Will take a futher look at it at another point. At this stage I'm just wanting to get the base funcationality working for the API and can address design issues later on. Thanks for the insight, really appreceiate it

Answer (score -1):

You could change the backref to 'searches' instead. Also see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/backref.html

```
teams = db.relationship('SearchTeam', backref='search')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, in fact doing this breaks the functionality. Turns out I needed to import the SearchTeam model into the Search model